# Error installing libpng-1.6.16 for matplotlib on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Hello there I am trying to install libpng-1.6.16 on mine Ubuntu 14.04.

Long story short can you help me whit this error http://ur1.ca/jj7ak.

I need this because I am trying to install matplotlib, so I can start working on mine python project.
Can someone help me overcome this tank you.

Comment: Is using `apt-get` not an option for you?

Comment: No i have tried, but I will try ti install matplotlib manualy, tnx for the tip @cel

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your build directory from "For Projects" to "ForProjects" (libtool seems to handle directory names with spaces in them poorly).

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solutions for mine first problem here https://github.com/pornel/pngquant/issues/19, I just needed to install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo app-get libpng-dev
```

Second I had a freetype-2.5.5 error and I have found mine solution here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/, for freetype I hade to

```
sudo apt-get libfreetype6-dev
```

after that I just pip install matplotlib in to mine env and everithing was fine.
Tank you @cel, @Glenn Randers-Pherson, @tcaswell